# Matlab 3d projectile secant method with vector

Tags: matlab, vector, projectile, runge-kutta

How can I use the secant method in order to calculate the angle b(between the positive x-axis and negative y-axis) I have to throw a ball for it to land on the x-axis, with these conditions:

the ball is thrown from origo, at a height z=1.4 m, with the and angle a (for the horizontal plane) 30◦, with a speed of 25 m / s. The air resistance coefficient is c = 0.070 and the wind force is 7 m / s at the ground which increases with the height according to: a(z) = 7 + 0.35z.

The motion of the ball is described with the following:
x''=−qx', y''=−q(y'−a(z)), z''=−9.81−qz', q=c*sqrt(x'^2+(y'−a(z))^2+z'^2)

I did a variable substitution (u) and then used RK4 to calculate the ball's motion, however **I can't figure out how to use the secant method to find the angle b. The problem is that when I plot with these start and guessing values is that the ball doesn't land on the x-axis**:

```
clear all, close all, clc

a = pi/3; %start angle
c = 0.07; % air resistance coeff.
v0 = 25; %start velocity, 25 m/s
t = 0; %start time
h = 0.1; % 0.1 second step
b = 0

x0 = 0; xPrim = v0*sin(a)*cosd(b);
y0 = 0; yPrim = v0*sin(a)*sind(b); 
z0 = 1.4; zPrim = v0*cos(a);

u = [x0 xPrim y0 yPrim z0 zPrim]';
uVek = u';

% Secant method
b0 = 270;   % Start guess nr 1
b1 = 360;    % Start guess nr 2
f0 = funk (b0);   
db = 1;   

while  abs(db) > 0.5e-8   
    f1 = funk (b1);   
    db = f1 * (b1 - b0) / (f1 - f0);   
    b0 = b1;   % Updates b0
    f0 = f1;   % Updates f0
    b1 = b1 - db   % new b
end

while u(5) >= 0 && u(3)<=0
    f1 = FRK4(t,u);
    f2 = FRK4(t+h/2,u+(h/2)*f1);
    f3 = FRK4(t+h/2,u+(h/2)*f2);
    f4 = FRK4(t+h,u+h*f3);
    f = (f1 + 2*f2 + 2*f3 + f4)/6;
    u = u + h*f;
    uVek = [uVek; u'];

    t = t+h;
end


x = uVek(:,1)'; y = uVek(:,3)'; z = uVek(:,5)';

plot3(x,y,z)
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Z');
grid on
```

where FRK4 is a function:

```
function uPrim = FRK4(t,u)
c = 0.07;
az = 7+0.35*(u(5));
q = c*sqrt(u(2)^2 +(u(4)- az)^2 + u(6)^2);
uPrim = [u(2) -q*u(2) u(4) -q*(u(4) - az) u(6) -9.81-q*u(6)]';
end
```

where funk is a function:

```
function f = funk(b)
a = pi/3
v0 = 25
x0 = 0; xPrim = v0*sin(a)*cosd(b);
y0 = 0; yPrim = v0*sin(a)*sind(b); 
z0 = 1.4; zPrim = v0*cos(a);

f = [x0 xPrim y0 yPrim z0 zPrim]';
end
```

Comment: `f1` is a vector output but you're treating it like a scalar.  You're second `while` loop is based on `u` but doesn't modify it.  That means it's not running or else it would be an infinite loop.  Also `f` is not yet defined at that point.  Variable `db` in the first `while` loop is a of size 6x6 when `abs(db)` is called.  I don't think this does what you think this does.

Comment: Your function `funk` should also contain an integration loop. The last value should be interpolated to get a better estimate where the ground is hit. You have two implementations of the secant method in the code, where the second one is incomplete or false, and redundant.